# sapply(a, replicate, b) expression no longer works inside a function

Tags: r, function, sapply, replicate

It's the first time I post here. I usually search for alternatives when I face bugs (or errors) but, since I'm about to go further and deeper in R, so I would be pleased to understand what's happening.

I made a simple example to reproduce the error:

[Simple R code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLSRk.png)

[Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKDvD.png)

So, it appears that, "manually", sapply(a,replicate,b) does work. However, that expression inside a function returns an error.
I searched about 1 hour on the web but I haven't found anything alike.

I thank you for your time,

Comment: Wellcome to stackoverflow. Please see here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example> in order to get best support.

Comment: Please don't add code as images, copy them as plain text.

Answer (score 6):

### Question

The question pointed out that even though the first line below succeeds the last line below fails with an error yet the only difference is that essentially the same line is within a function.

```
sapply(2, replicate, 3)
##      [,1]
## [1,]    3
## [2,]    3

doRep <- function(a, b) sapply(a, replicate, b)
doRep(3, 2)
## Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'b' not found
```

### Non-standard evaluation

The problem is that the second argument of `replicate` uses non-standard evaluation

```
replicate <- function (n, expr, simplify = "array") {
  sapply(integer(n), eval.parent(substitute(function(...) expr)), 
    simplify = simplify)
}
```

using `eval.parent` which refers to the caller of `replicate`; however, the caller of `replicate` is `sapply`, not `doRep` so `b` in `doRep(a, b)` is not found.

Another example of how this can go wrong is this:

```
sapply(2, replicate, str(FUN))
## function (n, expr, simplify = "array")  <--- Note
## function (n, expr, simplify = "array")  
##      [,1]
## [1,] NULL
## [2,] NULL
```

Evidently it matched the `FUN` argument within `sapply` which in this case was passed as `replicate`:

```
args(replicate)
## function (n, expr, simplify = "array")
```

### replicate2

If we add an `envir` argument to `replicate` and then pass the correct enviroment to look up b then it will work:

```
replicate2 <- function (n, expr, simplify = "array", envir = parent.frame()) {
  sapply(integer(n), eval(substitute(function(...) expr), envir), 
    simplify = simplify)
}
doRep2 <- function(a, b) sapply(a, replicate2, b, envir = environment())
doRep2(3, 2)
##      [,1]
## [1,]    2
## [2,]    2
## [3,]    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this limitation by creating a local function where you pass argument `b` in the normal way:

```
function(a, b) sapply(a, function(x) replicate(x, b))
```

Comment: Good idea although I do think that  this needs to be fixed in R so that such workarounds are not needed.